# Find the change of basis matrices from D to ε2 and from ε2 to D

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

> In $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $D = \{ [2, 1], [-2, 4] \}$ find the change of basis matrices from $D$ to $\mathcal{E}_2$ and from $\mathcal{E}_2$ to $D$.

I am having a hard time starting this problem because I do not know what $\mathcal{E}_2$ is. I am able to find information on changing from one basis to another where both are defined but not when using $\mathcal{E}_2$.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

**Edit**: Based on the comments;

Does this mean the change of basis matrix for D to ε2 would be:

`[2 -2]
 [1  4]`

And the change of basis matrix for ε2 to D would be:

`[1 0]
 [0 1]`

Comment: I also don't know what that is

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but could it be the canonical basis $\mathcal{E}_2 = \{[1, 0], [0,1] \}$?

Comment: So just the standard basis?

Comment: I've occasionally seen that used to denote the standard basis. I don't see what else it could mean without further context.

Comment: @caverac I've updated my post. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: no.. there are so many posts on change of basis already. Can you describe your understanding of it first?